# JavaScript not working in chrome but working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a website in which content changes when the user clicks on a toggle switch, the price changes from monthly to annual, and vice versa when a user clicks on the toggle i.e. the `h2` with the class `monthly` gets displayed when toggler is checked(true) and the `h2` with class `annual` gets displayed when toggler is unchecked(false).

```js
function refreshPage(){
    window.location.reload();
} 
const toggler = document.querySelector("#switch");
const annual = document.querySelectorAll(".annual");
const monthly = document.querySelectorAll(".monthly");
window.onload = function priceChange(){
    if (toggler.checked === false) {
        monthly.forEach(hideMonthly);
        function hideMonthly(item) {
            item.style.display = "none";
        }
    } else if (toggler.checked === true ) {
        annual.forEach(hideAnnual);
        function hideAnnual(item) {
            item.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
:root {
    --gradient: linear-gradient(to bottom right, hsl(236, 72%, 79%), hsl(237, 63%, 64%));
    --gradient-900: hsl(237, 63%, 64%);
    --neutral-grey-100: hsl(240, 78%, 98%);
    --neutral-grey-300: hsl(234, 14%, 74%);
    --neutral-grey-600: hsl(233, 13%, 49%);
    --neutral-grey-900: hsl(232, 13%, 33%);
    --neutral-100: #fff;
    --neutral-900: #000;
}

*,
*::after, 
*::before {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    background: #F6F6FE url("../images/bg-top.svg") no-repeat;
    background-position: top right -170px; 
    text-align: center;
}

.neutral-grey-100 {
    color: var(--neutral-grey-100);
}

.neutral-grey-300 {
    color: var(--neutral-grey-300);
}

.neutral-grey-600 {
    color: var(--neutral-grey-600);
}

.neutral-grey-900 {
    color: var(--neutral-grey-900);
}

h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    margin-bottom: .8em;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 3em;
    margin: 1rem 0;
}

.container {
    width: 85%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
    padding: 2.4em;
}

.card {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: var(--neutral-100);
    border-radius: .8em;
    padding: 1em 2.6em;
    margin-bottom: 2.5em;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.card:nth-child(odd) {
    background: var(--gradient);
    color: var(--neutral-100);
}

.card > div:not(:last-child) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(183, 184, 194, 0.45);
}

.card-inverse > div:not(:last-child) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35);
}

section div {
    padding: 1em 0;
}

.button {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 1em 2em;
    margin: 2.6em 0 1.2em 0;
    background: var(--gradient);
    border: 1px solid var(--neutral-100);
    border-radius: 6px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--neutral-100);
}

.button:hover, .button:focus {
    background: var(--neutral-100);
    border: 1px solid hsl(237, 63%, 24%);
    color: var(--gradient-900);
    outline: none;
}

.button-inverse {
    background: var(--neutral-100);
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--gradient-900);
}

.button-inverse:hover, .button-inverse:focus {
    background: hsl(237, 63%, 64%);
    border: 1px solid var(--neutral-100);
    color: var(--neutral-100);
    outline: none;
}

.attribution { 
    font-size: 11px; 
    text-align: center; 
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.attribution a { 
    color: hsl(228, 45%, 44%); 
}

/*-------- TOGGLER --------*/

 .toggle {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

input[type=checkbox]{
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

label {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 65px;
    height: 35px;
    background: var(--gradient);
    display: block;
    border-radius: 100px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 1.4em;
}

label:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    left: 4px;
    width: 27px;
    height: 27px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 110px;
    -webkit-transition: all 350ms;
        -moz-transition: all 350ms;
            transition: all 350ms; 
}

input:checked + label {
    background: var(--gradient);
}

input + label:hover, input + label:focus-within {
    background: hsl(236, 72%, 81%)
}

input:checked + label:after {
    transform: translate3d(114%, 0, 0);
}

@media (min-width: 1440px) {
    body {
        font-size: 16px;
        background-image: url("../images/bg-top.svg"), url("../images/bg-bottom.svg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
        background-position: 100% 0%, 0% 130%; 
        background-size: 24%, 24%;
    }

    .container {
        display: grid;   
        grid-template-areas: 
            "header header header"
            "basic professional master"
            "attribution attribution attribution"; 
        align-items: center;
        width: 65%;
    }

    .header {
        grid-area: header;
    }

    h2 {
        font-size: 4em;
    }

    h3 {
        font-size: 1.3033333333333335em;
    }

    .card-inverse {
        padding: 3em 2em;
    }

    .card {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    #basic {
        grid-area: basic;
        border-top-right-radius: 0;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    }
    
    #professional {
        grid-area: professional;
    }
    
    #master {
        grid-area: master;
        border-top-left-radius: 0;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    }

    .attribution {
        grid-area: attribution;
        margin-top: 4em;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script defer src="js/script.js"></script>
    <title>Frontend Mentor | Pricing component with toggle</title>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <section class="header">
            <h1 class="neutral-grey-900">Our Pricing</h1>
            <div class="toggle neutral-grey-300">
                Annually
                <input type="checkbox" id="switch" onClick="refreshPage()"/><label for="switch">Toggle</label>
                <!-- <label class="switch"><input type="checkbox" name="toggler" id="toggler" onClick="refreshPage()"/>    <figure></figure>
                </label> -->
                Monthly
            </div>
        </section>

        <section class="card" id="basic">
            <div>
                <h3 class="neutral-grey-600">Basic</h3>
            
                <h2 class="neutral-grey-900 monthly">&dollar;19.99</h2>
                <h2 class="neutral-grey-900 annual">&dollar;199.99</h2>
            </div>
            
            <div class="neutral-grey-600">500 GB Storage</div>
            
            <div class="neutral-grey-600">2 Users Allowed</div>
            
            <div class="neutral-grey-600">Send up to 3 GB</div>

            <a class="button button-main" href="">Learn More</a>
        </section>
        
        <section class="card card-inverse" id="professional">
            <div>
                <h3>Professional</h3>
            
                <h2 class="monthly">&dollar;24.99</h2>
                <h2 class="annual">&dollar;249.99</h2>
            </div>
            
            <div>1 TB Storage</div>
            
            <div>5 Users Allowed</div>
            
            <div>Send up to 10 GB</div>
            
            <a class="button button-inverse" href="">Learn More</a> 
        </section>

        <section class="card" id="master">
            <div>
                <h3 class="neutral-grey-600">Master</h3>
                
                <h2 class="neutral-grey-900 monthly">&dollar;39.99</h2>
                <h2 class="neutral-grey-900 annual">&dollar;399.99</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="neutral-grey-600">2 TB Storage</div>
            
            <div class="neutral-grey-600">10 Users Allowed</div>
            
            <div class="neutral-grey-600">Send up to 20 GB</div>
            
            <a class="button button-main" href="">Learn More</a> 
        </section>
        
        <div class="attribution">
            Challenge by <a href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank">Frontend Mentor</a>.
            Coded by <a href="#">Sachin Jadhav</a>.
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The toggle is working in Firefox but not in Chrome, I am not able to figure out what's wrong with my javascript.

Comment: This is not a [mcve]

Comment: Wow, it does actually behave differently in Firefox, because Firefox restores the state of the input. But I **wouldn't** rely on that. Instead, handle the change locally, without refreshing (and perhaps echo the current state to local storage so you can show the user's preference if they *do* reload at some point).

Comment: @Andreas - It's not **minimal**, for sure. :) But amazingly it does replicate the problem.

Comment: Oh my bad, I didn't realize that I had to minimize the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is relying on Firefox remembering the state of the `input` and restoring it before the `load` handler fires on subsequent page loads. That's not something you can rely on cross-browser.

Instead, just handle the toggle without refreshing. And instead of manually looping the items, you can use a class on their container (or even `body`) to control them:

```
toggler.addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.body.classList.toggle("show-monthly", toggler.checked);
});
```

(And removing `refreshPage` entirely.)

With this additional CSS:

```css
body .monthly {
    display: none;
}
body.show-monthly .monthly {
    display: block;
}
body.show-monthly .annual {
    display: none;
}
```

(Note that the second argument of `classList.toggle` doesn't work on obsolete browsers like IE, so you may need an `if`/`else` for those.)

```js
const toggler = document.querySelector("#switch");
const annual = document.querySelectorAll(".annual");
const monthly = document.querySelectorAll(".monthly");
toggler.addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.body.classList.toggle("show-monthly", toggler.checked);
});
```

```css
body .monthly {
    display: none;
}
body.show-monthly .monthly {
    display: block;
}
body.show-monthly .annual {
    display: none;
}

:root {
    --gradient: linear-gradient(to bottom right, hsl(236, 72%, 79%), hsl(237, 63%, 64%));
    --gradient-900: hsl(237, 63%, 64%);
    --neutral-grey-100: hsl(240, 78%, 98%);
    --neutral-grey-300: hsl(234, 14%, 74%);
    --neutral-grey-600: hsl(233, 13%, 49%);
    --neutral-grey-900: hsl(232, 13%, 33%);
    --neutral-100: #fff;
    --neutral-900: #000;
}

*,
*::after, 
*::before {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    background: #F6F6FE url("../images/bg-top.svg") no-repeat;
    background-position: top right -170px; 
    text-align: center;
}

.neutral-grey-100 {
    color: var(--neutral-grey-100);
}

.neutral-grey-300 {
    color: var(--neutral-grey-300);
}

.neutral-grey-600 {
    color: var(--neutral-grey-600);
}

.neutral-grey-900 {
    color: var(--neutral-grey-900);
}

h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    margin-bottom: .8em;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 3em;
    margin: 1rem 0;
}

.container {
    width: 85%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
    padding: 2.4em;
}

.card {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: var(--neutral-100);
    border-radius: .8em;
    padding: 1em 2.6em;
    margin-bottom: 2.5em;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.card:nth-child(odd) {
    background: var(--gradient);
    color: var(--neutral-100);
}

.card > div:not(:last-child) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(183, 184, 194, 0.45);
}

.card-inverse > div:not(:last-child) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35);
}

section div {
    padding: 1em 0;
}

.button {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 1em 2em;
    margin: 2.6em 0 1.2em 0;
    background: var(--gradient);
    border: 1px solid var(--neutral-100);
    border-radius: 6px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--neutral-100);
}

.button:hover, .button:focus {
    background: var(--neutral-100);
    border: 1px solid hsl(237, 63%, 24%);
    color: var(--gradient-900);
    outline: none;
}

.button-inverse {
    background: var(--neutral-100);
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--gradient-900);
}

.button-inverse:hover, .button-inverse:focus {
    background: hsl(237, 63%, 64%);
    border: 1px solid var(--neutral-100);
    color: var(--neutral-100);
    outline: none;
}

.attribution { 
    font-size: 11px; 
    text-align: center; 
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.attribution a { 
    color: hsl(228, 45%, 44%); 
}

/*-------- TOGGLER --------*/

 .toggle {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

input[type=checkbox]{
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

label {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 65px;
    height: 35px;
    background: var(--gradient);
    display: block;
    border-radius: 100px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 1.4em;
}

label:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    left: 4px;
    width: 27px;
    height: 27px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 110px;
    -webkit-transition: all 350ms;
        -moz-transition: all 350ms;
            transition: all 350ms; 
}

input:checked + label {
    background: var(--gradient);
}

input + label:hover, input + label:focus-within {
    background: hsl(236, 72%, 81%)
}

input:checked + label:after {
    transform: translate3d(114%, 0, 0);
}

@media (min-width: 1440px) {
    body {
        font-size: 16px;
        background-image: url("../images/bg-top.svg"), url("../images/bg-bottom.svg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
        background-position: 100% 0%, 0% 130%; 
        background-size: 24%, 24%;
    }

    .container {
        display: grid;   
        grid-template-areas: 
            "header header header"
            "basic professional master"
            "attribution attribution attribution"; 
        align-items: center;
        width: 65%;
    }

    .header {
        grid-area: header;
    }

    h2 {
        font-size: 4em;
    }

    h3 {
        font-size: 1.3033333333333335em;
    }

    .card-inverse {
        padding: 3em 2em;
    }

    .card {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    #basic {
        grid-area: basic;
        border-top-right-radius: 0;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    }
    
    #professional {
        grid-area: professional;
    }
    
    #master {
        grid-area: master;
        border-top-left-radius: 0;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    }

    .attribution {
        grid-area: attribution;
        margin-top: 4em;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <section class="header">
        <h1 class="neutral-grey-900">Our Pricing</h1>
        <div class="toggle neutral-grey-300">
            Annually
            <input type="checkbox" id="switch"/><label for="switch">Toggle</label>
            <!-- <label class="switch"><input type="checkbox" name="toggler" id="toggler" onClick="refreshPage()"/>    <figure></figure>
            </label> -->
            Monthly
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="card" id="basic">
        <div>
            <h3 class="neutral-grey-600">Basic</h3>

            <h2 class="neutral-grey-900 monthly">&dollar;19.99</h2>
            <h2 class="neutral-grey-900 annual">&dollar;199.99</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="neutral-grey-600">500 GB Storage</div>

        <div class="neutral-grey-600">2 Users Allowed</div>

        <div class="neutral-grey-600">Send up to 3 GB</div>

        <a class="button button-main" href="">Learn More</a>
    </section>

    <section class="card card-inverse" id="professional">
        <div>
            <h3>Professional</h3>

            <h2 class="monthly">&dollar;24.99</h2>
            <h2 class="annual">&dollar;249.99</h2>
        </div>

        <div>1 TB Storage</div>

        <div>5 Users Allowed</div>

        <div>Send up to 10 GB</div>

        <a class="button button-inverse" href="">Learn More</a> 
    </section>

    <section class="card" id="master">
        <div>
            <h3 class="neutral-grey-600">Master</h3>

            <h2 class="neutral-grey-900 monthly">&dollar;39.99</h2>
            <h2 class="neutral-grey-900 annual">&dollar;399.99</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="neutral-grey-600">2 TB Storage</div>

        <div class="neutral-grey-600">10 Users Allowed</div>

        <div class="neutral-grey-600">Send up to 20 GB</div>

        <a class="button button-main" href="">Learn More</a> 
    </section>

    <div class="attribution">
        Challenge by <a href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank">Frontend Mentor</a>.
        Coded by <a href="#">Sachin Jadhav</a>.
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want to remember the setting for future visits, store it in `localStorage` and use it when loading the page:

```
const updatePriceDisplay = () => {
    document.body.classList.toggle("show-monthly", toggler.checked);
};
toggler.checked = localStorage.getItem("show-monthly") === "Y";
updatePriceDisplay();
toggler.addEventListener("click", () => {
    updatePriceDisplay();
    localStorage.setItem("show-monthly", toggler.checked ? "Y" : "N");
});
```

Comment: Understood, thank you. This code is far better than what I had done. I just had a small doubt, if the 2nd argument in `document.body.classList.toggle("monthly", toggler.checked)` is false it removes the class `monthly` and if its true it adds the class, right? I removed the 2nd argument and tried and still the code was working as intended.

Comment: @SachinJadhav - That's right, that's what that argument does. I used it there so the checkbox and the class never get out of sync. (Also, I updated the answer -- I used the same class for the elements that should be shown/hidden and also the class on `body` that controls it, but that's just asking for confusion. :-) So I changed the one on `body` and the flag in local storage to `show-monthly` instead.)

Answer (score 1):

You set `onClick="refreshPage()"` on your switch. So the page always reloads when someone tries to change its value (en-/disable it).

The default behavior of chrome is to loose/forget all the data that was entered before a reload for a formular, while firefox normally asks (or if the user wants it without a popup, defaults) to reenter all the data the user entered after the reload.

Thats why the reload is resetting the value in chrome and keeping it in firefox.

I would recommend to just not reload the page. That also brings better usablity.